# Android Volley request weird "1 second" delay between multiple fast clicks

Tags: android, json, delay, android-volley, android-imagebutton

Sorry for my bad english, but i have problem and can't figure it out..

I have custom listview in my fragment for getting products from JSON array. And I have 3 ImageButtons in every listview row;

Plus Button(**+**), Minus Button(**-**) and Remove Button(**X**)..

So when i click each button, its calling JSON request for update product's piece number, getting new datas from response and repopulate array list.

Everything ok but, when I click that buttons faster, it seems there is **1 sec** delay between multiple requests even first volley request has already done before.

Here is my JSON method in **TableAdapter.java**

```
public void JSON(final int position, final int process) {

    if (inProgress==false) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext);
        dialog.setMessage("Updating.....");
        dialog.show();
        inProgress = true;
        System.out.println("**** Now request is beginning............");

        final int rowID = tableModelList.get(position).getID();
        final int treeID = tableModelList.get(position).getAna_dal();
        final float price = tableModelList.get(position).getBFiyat();
        final int quantity = tableModelList.get(position).getAdet();
        final int print = tableModelList.get(position).getYazdimi();

        final String insertUrl = "http://"+getServer+"/t6mobilservice/order-piece.php";

        Map<String, String> parameters  = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("tableID", "" + getTableId);
        parameters.put("rowID", "" + rowID);
        parameters.put("treeID", ""+treeID);
        parameters.put("process",""+process);
        parameters.put("quantity",""+quantity);
        parameters.put("price",""+price);
        parameters.put("print",""+print);

        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray getOrders = response.getJSONArray("order");

                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    tableModelList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < getOrders.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject order = getOrders.getJSONObject(i);

                        TableModel tableModel = gson.fromJson(order.toString(), TableModel.class);
                        tableModelList.add(tableModel);
                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    System.out.println("**** onResponse: Request is done............");
                    System.out.println("**** JSON: "+response.toString());

                    dialog.cancel();
                    inProgress = false;

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
                Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
                inProgress = false;
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

Dialog is showing when request beginning and canceling when request is done. But as I said, when I click faster, there is a delay between multiple requests even first request has already done. I'm saying **1 sec**, because 2nd request is beginning after **1 sec** exactly, no matter how I clicking fast. I can't figure it out..

I tested fast clicks to showing toasts with random numbers and it's working fine. But when I testing with JSON method, there is a weird delay.

I have *SwipeRefreshLayout* and *ScrollView* in my fragment.
I'm using Volley with singleton.

**EDIT 1. :** Here's [a video link](https://youtu.be/4oGUAOZMnkw) to showing what my problem is..

**EDIT 2. :** Here's [a LogCat output video](https://youtu.be/oaChhvam2Tg) for every click

Every fast click has returning success json output, but nothing change instantly..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: simply create boolean inProgress, and don't start the same Request if inProgress == true, and when Request is onResponse or onErrorResponse set inProgress = false;

Comment: @VladimirKulyk thanks for advice, i did it. I'm checking boolean **inProgress**, if it's **false**, then change it to **inProgress=true** and doing request.. onResponse or onErrorResponse turning it to **false**.. if it's already **true**, then do nothing. But I've still same problem because as I said first request successfully done in second. There is still 1 second delay for 2nd request. I'm editing my question, adding video link. You can see what the problem is

Comment: @Tevfic I sow your video, your app works correct, 1st click start request, 2,3... fast clicks do nothing, because 1st did not finish yet, after 1st has finished next request will start and so on. You may create queue (LinkedList<Integer>) and put there number on Button click, and after 1st request is finished you take next value from LinkedList and start next Request

Comment: @VladimirKulyk If my app works correct, why dialog is showing in every click ? Because dialog must appears only when `inProgress=false`. If **1st request** hasn't finished yet, then **inProgress** is still **true**. So why dialog is showing ? I can see the output from Logcat. Every fast click has returning with success output. Adding a **new video** for Logcat output for you. As you can see, every clicks works fine but nothing change instantly.. Somethings going wrong with this.. Thanks for support